# How to list users in the Office 365 Germany domain using MS Graph API?

Tags: rest, azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to list the users in an Office 365 Germany domain. I am using the MS Graph API.
I registered my application in Azure AD with all application permissions.
I can get an access token, but when I try to send next request to list the users in organization

```
GET https://graph.cloudapi.de/v1.0/users
```

I get error response:

```
{  
   "odata.error":{  
      "code":"Request_DataContractVersionMissing",
      "message":{  
         "lang":"en",
         "value":"The specified api-version is invalid. The value must exactly match a supported version."
      }
   }
}
```

When I do the same on Microsoft Graph global service using this request

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

everything works fine and I can get list of users in response.
What I missed or doing wrong? How can I get the list of users in the Office 365 Germany domain using MS Graph API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Microsoft Graph Germany](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/deployments) endpoint is

> https://graph.microsoft.de

So please try this URI https://graph.microsoft.de/v1.0/users.

> https://graph.cloudapi.de

is the [Azure AD Graph Germany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/developing-for-partner-center-for-microsoft-national-cloud#partner_center_cloud_germany) endpoint.